# Mysql Помогите оптимизировать запрос

Tags: mysql

```
$mysql_query  = "SELECT "
. "(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=1 AND user=$id) AS game, "
. "(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=4 AND user=$id) AS discount, "
. "(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=3 AND user=$id) AS salery, "
. "(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE (oper=2 OR oper=12) AND user=$id) AS costs ";
```

В данный момент приходиться вытаскивать массив из этой же таблицы с кучей АйДи(user) и запускать цикл каждый раз выбирая строку с пользователем. Подскажите можно ли как то это дело собрать в один запрос.

P.S. `$users = "SELECT DISTINCT user, user_name FROM transactions"`

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся если кому интересно, то вот результаты: выбор каждой ячейки по отдельности (способ неописанный здесь внешний цикл перебирает юзеров внутренний операции) 51.7 секунда на 10к, описанный в вопросе цикл по пользователям 22.4 и ответ от Mike 4,9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user, user_name,
       SUM(if(oper=1,sum,0)) as game,
       SUM(if(oper=4,sum,0)) as discount,
       SUM(if(oper=3,sum,0)) as salery,
       SUM(if(oper=2 or oper=12,sum,0)) as costs
  FROM transactions
 WHERE oper in(1,2,3,4,12)
 GROUP BY user, user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну и нельзя не добавить, что 
1) в php можно задавать многострочные строковые переменные
2) подставлять параметры лучше через prepared statement

```
$mysql_query  = "
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=1 AND user=?) AS game, 
(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=4 AND user=?) AS discount, 
(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE oper=3 AND user=?) AS salery,
(SELECT SUM(sum)FROM transactions WHERE (oper=2 OR oper=12) AND user=?) AS costs
";
$stmt = $db->prepare($mysql_query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiii',$id,$id,$id,$id);
$stmt->execute();
```