# Как посчитать количество элементов за определенное время с условием GROUP BY по date в каждом столбце

Tags: mysql, sql

**Есть вот такая табл. пример(если убрать GROUP BY из подзапросов)** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в которой нужно посчитать кол. товара за определенный промежуток времени по статусам с условием GROUP BY по дате.

**база**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**и код :**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_id,  SUM(summ) as total_summ,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM orders WHERE status='no' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt) as s1,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM orders WHERE status='waitstock' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt) as s2,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM orders WHERE status='cancel-other' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt) as s3,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM orders WHERE status='complete' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') as c1,
        (SELECT SUM(summ) FROM orders WHERE status='complete' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2') as c2,
        statusUpdatedAt, status FROM orders WHERE status='complete' AND statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt
```

Но при попытке посчитать каждый статус с GROUP BY по дате выбивает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать запрос ?

Comment: так вы тот ответ почитали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535019/mysql-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/535047#535047  вам надо так же, без подзапросов, одной выборкой, с помощью `if()` развернуть статусы в нужные колонки

Comment: @Akina Лучше тот старый закрывать. Очевидно, что ТС когда писал тот вопрос, нормально не зарегистрировался и сейчас потерял контроль над тем аккаунтом (поэтому не мог там писать комменты и написал их ответом). А на этом аккаунте он явно нормально прошел регистрацию

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое! сейчас буду пробовать, да вы все верно указали старый вопрос можно удалять.

Comment: И да, вместо count() проще всего использовать `sum(status='no')` потому, что логическое условие само по себе дает 0 или 1 и таким образом sum считает единички у строк где условие совпало

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Всё действительно заработало, но как мне теперь посчитать сумму, а не количество через SUM(IF) ?

Comment: `sum(if(status='complete',summ,0))` ну или даже `sum((status='complete')*summ)` (просто умножаем текущую сумму на 0 или 1) хотя можно и так как написали ниже в ответе через case, он то же самое делает просто длинее выглядит (зато есть практически во всех СУБД, в отличие от IF который только в MySQL)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Всё четко работает, а если теперь мне нужно общую сумму и количество выводить мне нужно подзапрос делать вот код     `SELECT *,
   SUM(IF(status='no' , 1 , 0)) as no,
   SUM(IF(status='complete' , 1 , 0)) as complete,
   SUM(IF(status='waitstock' , 1 , 0)) as waitstock,
   SUM(IF(status='cancel-other' , 1 , 0)) as cancel,
   SUM(IF(status='complete' , summ , 0)) as complete_summ
   FROM orders
   WHERE statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
   GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt `

Comment: попробуйте `with rollup` добавить после group by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_id,  SUM(summ) as total_summ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='waitstock' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='cancel-other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS s3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='complete' THEN summ ELSE 0 END) AS c2,
    statusUpdatedAt
    FROM orders 
    WHERE statusUpdatedAt BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' GROUP BY statusUpdatedAt
```