# Как составить запрос и транспонировать таблицу?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

***Имеем:*** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите составить запрос, дающий результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где будут выведены суммарные продажи сотрудников, сгруппированные по годам, причем только тех сотрудников, у которых суммарные продажи за 3 года больше 100. Значение с пустым "emp" выводится обязательно.

Comment: Используйте условное суммирование, т.е. в каждую из явно указанных колонок суммируете записи определенного года. Примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535047/194569

Answer (score 0):

как то так

SELECT u.nemp,s.god,SUM(s.sales) as count_sales FROM sales s LEFT JOIN users u ON(s.emp=u.idEmp) WHERE count_sales >=100 AND s.god > 2015 GROUP BY s.god ORDER BY u.nemp

Comment: USE Ex;
SELECT 
              god
             ,SUM(Sales) AS count_sales
             ,nemp
FROM Sales 
LEFT JOIN Emp ON Sales.emp = Emp.idEmp
WHERE god >2015
GROUP BY god, nemp
ORDER BY nemp

Вывел лишь отфильтрованные записи. Как в данном запросе вывести года как столбцы?